# ArangoDB: having a few large collections vs. a lot small collections

Tags: arangodb

I have a question regarding performance/best practice:

**Scenario:** I have a user-collection and a chatbot-collection. They can be a lot of users (lets say 100 -1000 users) in the user-collection. Each user can have multiple chatbots (around 10 per user).

**Option A:** I create an edge collection to define the connection between user -> chatbot. At the end I would have 1 user-collection, 1 chatbot-collection (containing all chatbots from all users) and 1 edge-collection (containing the definitions from a user to its chatbots)

**Option B:** I create a separate chatbot-collection for each user, to have all chatbots of a specific user in one place. Chatbot-collection name would be e.g. user_xyz(user._key)_chatbots. So if I need all chatbots of a user with the _key ‚abc‘, I would check the collection user_abc_chatbots. In this case I don’t need an edge collection for the connection user -> chatbot. At the end I would have 1 user-collection and a lot of user_xyz_chatbots-collections (depending on how many users I have - can be 100-1000 as I wrote before).

**Now my question:** What is the better option? Also regarding performance - Image I have to get all (or a specific) chatbot of a user each time I receive a request.

Would be awesome if you can give me feedback on your experience/thoughts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the numbers you posted, i.e. 100 - 1000 users and about 10 chatbots per user, this would mean just 1000 to 10000 chatbots in total.

For this dimension of data, I would say it makes more sense to store all chatbots in a single collection, and use an (indexed) attribute to store the user id for each chatbot. This is a 1:n relationship (1 user mapped to n chatbots)

That way you can easily and still quickly find all chatbots mapped to a particular user, but this setup will also allow you to make analyses for all users or all chatbots easily.

This would be much more difficult to achieve if the chatbots of each user would be located in a different collection.

In addition, if the same chatbots can be mapped to multiple users, it may actually make sense to use three collections:

- one collection for users
- one collection for chatbots
- and one mapping collection between users and chatbots

This would be an n:m relationship, in which each user can still be mapped to any number of chatbots, but if multiple users are mapped to the same chatbot, the data of each chatbot does not need to be stored redundantly.

I would only recommend to use separate chatbot collections per user if each chatbot has an individual data structure that is separate from all others, and that needs special indexing or querying. In this case it may make sense to separate different chatbots.

However, having too many collections (here we would think of at most 1,000) also isn't great, because each collection has a small overhead even when empty. This amortized much better if there are fewer collections that are used more frequently than when having many collections which are used seldomly.